# Remove Qt widget layout's margins

Tags: c++, macos, qt, layout

I want to remove the spacing marked as red lines in the screenshot.
I set layout's contents margins to (0,0,0,0), re-sized parent widget to minimum but still can not get rid of those spaces.
This only happens on Mac. 
Looking for some help. 
Thanks in advance!
[image: screenshoot]

Comment: M... ui->layout->setSpacing(0); ?

Comment: Already set setSpacing(0). Didn't work.

Comment: try combine setMargin / setSpacing / setContentMargings. That is weird that Mac OS port has this problem while the rest of platforms don't. I also wonder what QPushButton objects size policy?

Comment: I see. I realized that QFrame, QWidget (when added to layout) wont have this problem. Also, dont know why it only happen with QPushbutton, if I switch to QToolButton the spaces gone.

Comment: Welcome to the weird size policies on Mac. I had similar problems with my application. It renders as expected on Windows and Ubuntu. I ended up writing a separate style sheet for Mac to overcome these kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

[image: QPushButton]

As nnb told, welcome to the weird size policies on mac.
But you can wrap layout to widget and crop margins.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The spaces are still there. I guess this problem is specific to QPushButton.

Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Yes, ofc. This is mac-specific implementation of qpushbutton. Also you can try create own implementation of qpushbutton using inheritance